# How to simplify a string of executable code for PyJulia

Tags: python, julia, call, executable

I want to use julia inside python to speed up some of the code that is slow. Therefore I installed the `PyJulia` package. As some Julia command are several lines long, I'm writing string of executable code that I pass to Julia. However, the strings are complex to read. Moreover, I would prefer to have as a string as I want to work in a Jupyter Notebook and want to have every piece of code visible in one file. Here is the code:

```
import julia
from julia import Base
from julia import Main
from julia import DataFrames

jst = "using DataFrames; \
df = DataFrame(A = [1,2,4,6], B = ['M', 'F', 'F', 'M']);\
for i in 1:length(df.A);\
    if df[i,:A] > 3;\
        println(df[i,:A]);\
    end;\
end;\
"
Main.eval(jst)
```

Is there a way to simplify the the string `jst`?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Simplify how? In what way?

Comment: This question is about how to use a multiline string. Nothing to do with `Julia` and/or `PyJulia`. Consider editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I guess what you're looking for is **multiline string** declaration. This'll not simplify the string, rather makes it easier to read as a code snippet and fits well within the code.
- Using `"""` you can declare a code snippet within your code and use it for execution.

```py
jst = """

using DataFrames;
df = DataFrame(A = [1,2,4,6], B = ['M', 'F', 'F', 'M']);
for i in 1:length(df.A);
    if df[i,:A] > 3;
        println(df[i,:A]);
    end;
end;

""".strip() # remove trailing & leading spaces
```